# How best to retrieve user data from Active Directory in conjunction with SQL Server data

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a web application which stores it's data in an Azure SQL database and data about authenticated users in Azure Active Directory B2C.  Data in the SQL Database relates to AD users by their "oid" (GUID).  This means that obtaining the database doesn't allow anyone to identify specific users.

However, when I query the SQL data to create a table or chart to a visitor, I obviously want to display the data in relation to the user owning the data (i.e. show the user's full name, not their oid!).

I know I can use the [Azure Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) to get user data when rendering the results of the SQL query on a web page but this seems like a highly inefficient way of doing it. Added to which, I'm not sure how i'd pass in a batch of oid's to get all the user objects back without using a ridiculously long query string filter!

I could create some sort of syncing process that queries the whole AD)
and updates a SQL table on a timed process (maybe an Azure Function) but that also seems horribly inefficient?

I looked at Microsoft Graph API webhooks but at the moment, there doesn't seem to be any subscription I can hook into with regards to User object changes and they don't recommend Graph with B2C.

The other option I guess would be to have a cache somewhere which stores the data for faster lookup but this would have to updated to.

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually (assuming you are already authenticated). Use this as your template for the GET request:

```
{baseUrl}/{tenantId}/users/{oid}?api-version={api-version}
```

Don't forget to add your bearer token to the Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
```

Also, here is an example of an object you might use for the response (in Java), with some helpful methods for retrieving the signup email (assuming you are using built in B2C users instead of third party, like google):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GraphApiUserExample{

    @JsonProperty("objectId")
    private String id;

    private Boolean accountEnabled;

    private com.brmic.azure.graph.api.client.model.PasswordProfile PasswordProfile;

    private List<SignInName> signInNames;

    private String surname;

    private String displayName;

    private String givenName;

    @JsonProperty("userPrincipalName")
    private String userPrincipalName;

    public String getId(){

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id){

        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getAccountEnabled(){

        return accountEnabled;
    }

    public void setAccountEnabled(final Boolean accountEnabled){

        this.accountEnabled = accountEnabled;
    }

    public com.brmic.azure.graph.api.client.model.PasswordProfile getPasswordProfile(){

        return PasswordProfile;
    }

    public void setPasswordProfile(final com.brmic.azure.graph.api.client.model.PasswordProfile passwordProfile){

        PasswordProfile = passwordProfile;
    }

    public List<SignInName> getSignInNames(){

        return signInNames;
    }

    public void setSignInNames(final List<SignInName> signInNames){

        this.signInNames = signInNames;
    }

    public String getSurname(){

        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(final String surname){

        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getDisplayName(){

        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(final String displayName){

        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getGivenName(){

        return givenName;
    }

    public void setGivenName(final String givenName){

        this.givenName = givenName;
    }

    public String getUserPrincipalName(){

        return userPrincipalName;
    }

    public void setUserPrincipalName(final String userPrincipalName){

        this.userPrincipalName = userPrincipalName;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getSignInEmail(){

        String email = "";
        if(signInNames != null){
            for(SignInName signInName : signInNames){
                if(signInName.getType().equals("emailAddress")){
                    email = signInName.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return email;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setSignInEmail(String signInEmail){

        if(signInNames == null){
            signInNames = new ArrayList<>();
            signInNames.add(new SignInName("emailAddress", signInEmail));
            return;
        }

        for(SignInName signInName : signInNames){
            if(signInName.getType().equals("emailAddress")){
                signInName.setValue(signInEmail);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pull multiple users, you can add a query instead of the 'oid' to filter and page through the results.

```
{baseUrl}/{tenantId}/users?api-version={api-version}&$skiptoken={skiptoken}&$top={top}&$filter={attributeOne} eq '{valueOne}'
{baseUrl}/{tenantId}/users?api-version={api-version}&$skiptoken={skiptoken}&$top={top}$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value eq '{email}')
```

Which returns a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "users":[...],
    "odata":{
        "nextLink": "{baseUrl}/{tenantId}/users?api-version={api-version}&$skiptoken={skiptoken}&$top={top}&$filter={attributeOne} eq '{valueOne}'"
        "metadata": "I forget if this is just a string or a parsable JSON object."
    }

}
```

You will still have the problem of matching the results of the query to your DB results, which is going to be a heavy operation.
I suggest that you use cache the results in a table for joins if you need to run faster operations.
It does feel kludgey, but only because it is.

There are also some powershell commands from the B2C azure powershell module you could use, and you could use ADAL to create a job in SQL Server for updating the contents of your table or view.

Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Pytry - I already have code which can call the API per row using the Authenticated GET request with each oid.  My point is that I'd need to do this once per row in the resulting output on the web page.  This feels horribly inefficient so I was looking for ways of mitigating this - someway of passing a bunch of oid's in one go?

Comment: This ended up being the way I went with it but doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you soon (been busy). You can also add a query to get multiple users at once, and then run additional filters/validation to match it with data from SQL Server. There's no getting around the heaviness of this kind of operation; if you need rapid access to the results then start looking into caching. Gimme a bit (hopefully today) to update my answer to include multiple results queries.

Comment: I updated my answer with a few suggestions to try and help out.